# Reading a huge file in Python: Why am I getting a Segmentation Fault?

Tags: python, memory, segmentation-fault

I know I shouldn't read the whole file into memory at once, but I'm not doing that.

I thought maybe I was doing something memory-heavy inside the loop, and got rid of everything until I was left with this:

```
with open("huge1.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        pass
```

It gave me a Segmentation Fault.

If I got everything right, iterating over a file like that is lazy and shouldn't load more than one line at a time into memory.

I also tried using `islice`, but with the same results.

My file is line based, the lines are all short and the size of the file is around 6 GB.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's something else going on, if it'll be about memory you'll be getting [MemoryError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError).

Comment: Do you happen to know how long is the longest line in your file?

Comment: @spectras: They should all be less than 20 characters long. Is there a simple way to check that I don't have a longer line by accident?

Comment: if you use a gnu-based system, `wc -L huge1.txt` should do the trick

Comment: @spectras: You were right, looks like there's an unexpected huge line somewhere in the file. You can right that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Maybe you have an unknown line delimiter and the whole file is considered as a single huge line. Windows formatting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segmentation fault should not occur no matter what, because python interpreter should catch errors and raise exceptions in the language. So your python interpreter has a bug for sure.

Now, as for what could trigger the bug. You read the file line by line, discarding each line once you have read the next line (actually retaining 2 lines at a time, because the previous line cannot be discarded until the assignment of the next line is complete).

So, if it runs out of memory (which is a likely reason for a segmentation fault, like in [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) returning `NULL` and the caller failing to check the return value), it is probably because some of the lines are still too big.

If you run a GNU/something system, you can run `wc -L huge1.txt` to check the length of the longest line.

If you do have a very long line, either it is a problem with the file and you can just fix it, or you will need to resort to reading the file block by block instead of line by line, using `f.read(2**20)`

And if you feel like helping the python developers, you could submit a bug report as well. The interpreter should never segfault.

Answer (score 1):

Try/except will give you an idea where the problem is

```
with open("huge1.txt", "r") as f:
    ctr=0
    previous=""
    try:
        for line in f:
            ctr += 1
            previous=line
    except:
        print(ctr, previous)
```